# What is causing my type-mismatch and how do I fix

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I am trying to do an average if calculation but in VBA without the worksheet function. I am getting a type mismatch error related to this line but don't know why or how to fix?

```vb
sumall = sumall + data_set(i, 19)
```

```vb
Sub segment_trigger_returns()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim segment_trigger As Boolean
    Dim data_set As Variant
    data_set = Range("A4:AV75617")
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To UBound(data_set, 1)
        Dim sumall As Long
        Dim cnt As Long
        cnt = 0
        sumall = 0
        company_name_curperiod = data_set(i, 3)
        company_name_prevperiod = data_set(i - 1, 3)
        segments_curperiod = data_set(i, 10)
        segments_prevperiod = data_set(i - 1, 10)

        If company_name_curperiod = company_name_prevperiod And segments_curperiod <> segments_prevperiod Then
            sumall = sumall + data_set(i, 19)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next i

    If cnt > 0 Then
        Sheets("Control").Range("K6") = sumall / cnt
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure `data_set(i, 19)` is giving you back a number?

Comment: Check if `data_set(i, 19)` is of type `Long` (or a type that can be implicitly converted to `Long`, like `Integer`) You can use the `TypeName` function for that. If for instance `data_set(i, 19)` is of type `String`, you cannot add it, at least until you cast whatever is in `data_set(i, 19)` to  value that you can add to a Long.

Answer (score -2):

To debug your code run this version and when the code stops at the "stop" line, step though it to see if data_set(i, 19) is a number or not.

```
Sub segment_trigger_returns()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim segment_trigger As Boolean
    Dim data_set As Variant
    data_set = Range("A4:AV75617")
    Dim i As Long, s as string

    For i = 2 To UBound(data_set, 1)
        Dim sumall As Long
        Dim cnt As Long
        cnt = 0
        sumall = 0
        company_name_curperiod = data_set(i, 3)
        company_name_prevperiod = data_set(i - 1, 3)
        segments_curperiod = data_set(i, 10)
        segments_prevperiod = data_set(i - 1, 10)

        If company_name_curperiod = company_name_prevperiod And segments_curperiod <> segments_prevperiod Then
            stop
            s = data_set(i, 19)
            If IsNumeric(s) then MsgBox "Yes, it's a number"
            sumall = sumall + data_set(i, 19)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next i

    If cnt > 0 Then
        Sheets("Control").Range("K6") = sumall / cnt
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```